# using npx create-react-app newapp command but after certain time it show 57 packages are looking for funding

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Sriharan>npx create-react-app newapp
npx: installed 99 in 95.306s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Sriharan\newapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Sriharan\newapp\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Users\Sriharan\newapp\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Users\Sriharan\newapp\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- cra-template@1.0.3
- react-scripts@3.4.1
- react@16.13.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
  added 1581 packages from 750 contributors and audited 931146 packages in 747.993s

57 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
_

Comment: It's normal...no problem.

Comment: @sri haran You can ignore this, however if you are grateful to be using such wonderful open-source tools, you can express your gratitude by funding the fellow devs. Hence the command `npm-fund`

Answer (score 1):

This is Normal. It's a new 'feature' added to Node from one of the recent updates.
Crowd-funded apps, or devs looking for $$$ for the work they put in. From what I've seen, its all on the up and up. Feel free to contribute if youre in a position to do so.

https://hub.packtpub.com/npm-install-funding-experiment-to-sustain-open-source-projects-with-ads-on-the-cli-terminal-faces-community-backlash/

This is just the latest form of this trend, as opens-source has been looking for funding since god was a boy.

Consider it like buying your friend's mix tape, but instead of crappy music, the product is something you'll actually use and it's free. So go on ahead and kick your people out a few bucks for the cause.